# Wordpress Central User Database

Tags: plugins, users, user-registration

I run multiple Wordpress sites, I would like to centralize the users table so that users can access all the sites with a single username.

Why do this? I run video communities
What do I need? User X can access sites a b c d without registering to each website.

The question is.. is it feasible? if so how?

Can anyone please advice a better aproach of what do I need to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress can be used as [Network or Multisite install](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) (different words, same topic). There you only got one central database table for all users.